# remove the "This database has been opened read-only. You can only change data in linked tables. To make design changes make a copy of the database"

Tags: ms-access

I have created an Access database ACCDE file and I have created an installation with inno set up.

When I install the app and run the database which I have created with inno set up it opens in a read-only mode.

What can I do so the installed database to open in exclusive mode and do not appear the message

> This database has been opened read-only. You can only change data in linked tables. To make design changes make a copy of the database

Comment: Have you researched this topic? Have you tried anything to correct?

Comment: Where does your database get installed? What folder on the user's machine?

Comment: it is installed on C:\Users\Document...

Comment: i have add the folder as a trusted location, but it is not the issue

Comment: Did you checked the file attributes of the database that it does not have the attribute "read only"? Are you sure that the user has write permissions in the installation folder?

Comment: Hello, it doesn't have the "read only" attribute. The original ACCDB front end file opens without the "read only", the ACCDE file also opens without this issue, but when i create the instalation file with inno set up then the database opens in read only. it is not something that i don't want. but i don't want the messageto be appeared.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. when you are creating the instalation file with inno set up, there is a step where you choose if you want the app to be installed for the curent user or for the hole machine and for any user. I had to choose only for the current user.
thank you!